# How can I found out if a string exists in my htmlDoc using JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'd like a smiley face if the class "film-profile" exists in my html document

Ive tried putting in simple text like " " but when I put a class name in, it still gives me the :( even though that class does exist.

Here is the code that I am using at the moment

```
if(htmlDoc.text().contains("film-profile")) {
        System.out.println(":)");
} else {
        System.out.println(":(");
}
```

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
if(Jsoup.connect("yourURL").get().select(".film-profile").size()!=0){
   System.out.println(":)");
} else {
   System.out.println(":(");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has sorted the issue. If you don't mind could you explain the size method? I'm new to java. Is it to just return a boolean value? So if it isnt 0 it must have found ".film-profile" Thanks again!

Comment: with the select method we are able to perform html/css search related activities. In this case ".film-profile" means search for references to the css class called film-profile (the dot denotes css class). That returns back Elements and by calling size() method we are basically asking whether we found any results. Lastly checking !=0 ensures we found at least one therefore success otherwise failure. If you are happy with the response you can upvote too. You can find more examples here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Thanky you very much. I think Ive upvoted now? I'm new to this site.